# Not able to make xmpp connection between my app server and GCM's CCS using XMPPHP library

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, xmpphp

Like push-notification(downstream message), I want to implement upstream messaging from my android device to my app server in php.

I am using this XMPPHP library from Github to connect my app server to GCM's CCS. But when I try to execute below code to connect GCM's CCS:

```
include 'XMPPHP/XMPP.php';
$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('gcm-preprod.googleapis.com', 5236, '<myProjectId>@gcm.googleapis.com', '<myApiKey>', 'xmpphp', 'http://myserverdomain', $printlog=true, $loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_INFO);
$conn->autoSubscribe();
$vcard_request = array();
try {
  $conn->connect();
...
```

I am getting following error.

```
1455354076 [INFO]: Connecting to tls://gcm-preprod.googleapis.com:5236 1455354106 [ERROR]: Could not connect. Could not connect before timeout.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably caused by the fact that [CCS doesn't currently support the STARTTLS extension](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs). I had the sampe problem with elixir and hedwig ([see here](https://github.com/hedwig-im/hedwig/issues/23)).

Sadly I don't have enough php knowledge to check whether your XMPP library supports this, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190038/unable-to-connect-to-google-cloud-connection-server) SO thread can help you to get started with CCS and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

there is answer on a question similar to your problem here [Not able to connect my app server to GCM's CCS using XMPPHP](http://phponlinesupport.com/531113/connect-app-server-gcm%26%2339-ccs-xmpphp). of course if you have not been the questioner there. i hope it works.